# How to click on an image link using selenium resulting in TimeoutException error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on the first image that appears for a given search in Flickr using Selenium as the code shows:

```
image = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@style,'transform: translate(0px, 0px)')]//a[@role='heading']")))
image.click()
```

I've tried doing it step by step in python's IDLE and it works flawlessly but when i run the script it raises a `TimeoutException` as if the webelement never gets clickable. 
Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Could it be that more than 30 seconds are needed? Also, please post your complete code as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as show the complete stacktrace. Thanks.

Comment: Why tinkering with `style` when there are clear indication of stong `Css` available? How about using _class_ attribute?

Comment: No it cant, it takes least than 10 seconds . Its very important to notice that it works just fine using the IDLE. @alecxe

Comment: i'm super new with CSS and Xpaths. It seemed that the only thing that changes from picture to picture was the transform property inside the style attribute. Didnt find anything else to differentiate between pictures @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not clickable because the element is overlapped by other and need to `hover` to make the `<a>` element to be clickable, simple solution is to change condition to `.presence_of_element_located()`

Comment: This actually worked. I've also used a  CSS selector as @DebanjanB suggested.

      `WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.view.photo-list-view>div.view.photo-list-photo-view.awake a.overlay[href*='photos']"))).click()`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) within the [url](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=jungle)  to click on the first image that appears for a given search in Flickr using Selenium instead of using the *style* attribute I would suggest to use a more reliable attribute as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.view.photo-list-view>div.view.photo-list-photo-view.awake a.overlay[href*='photos']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='view photo-list-view']/div[@class='view photo-list-photo-view awake']//a[@class='overlay' and @role='heading'][contains(@href, 'photos')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It didnt solve the problem but i'll take the advice. Thanks @DebanjanB